# Selenium IDE > add command

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How do you add a command AFTER an existing command with Selenium IDE?

If I right click there's an `Insert New Command` but that always adds the command BEFORE the existing command.

Answer (score 0):

By default selenium ide adds a line just ahead of the line you selected and let you to choose the commands from drop down. Now, if you need this particular command after your desired command, then use source section to move the section(code snippet) of command.

[image]

Use Source to move the commands,

[image]